# Getting a build error with vue2 and node 18

Tags: vue.js, npm, dependencies, node-modules, npm-build

**Here are my dependecies, It serves but it wont build, see error below.**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "core-js": "^3.33.3",
    "dwnld-attr-polyfill": "^1.1.7",
    "element-resize-detector": "^1.2.4",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "fastclick": "^1.0.6",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "markdown-it": "^8.4.2",
    "nid": "^0.3.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
    "recaptcha-v3": "^1.10.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "store": "^2.0.12",
    "url-parse": "^1.5.10",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.1.3",
    "vue": "^2.7.15",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.5",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.8",
    "vue-popperjs": "^2.3.0",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-recaptcha-v3": "^1.9.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.6.5",
    "vue-screen": "^1.5.6",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.20.0",
    "vue-timeago": "^5.1.3",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.19",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "cssnano": "5.0.0-rc.2",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "postcss-import": "^13.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.9.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.15"
  },
```

**Error I am getting**

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    10:35:28 AM
>
> error  in ./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7161f124&prod&lang=scss&scoped=true
>
> TypeError: plugin is not a function
>
> @ ./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7161f124&prod&lang=scss&scoped=true 1:0-560 1:0-560
> @ ./src/views/Home.vue
> @ ./src/router.js
> @ ./src/main.js
> multi ./src/main.js
>
> ERROR  Build failed with errors.

I tired upgrading and downgrading the dependecies thinking that might be the issue.
I uninstalled and reinstalled sass-loader.

I removed the node-moduels and the package-lock file and did an npm install again but nothing.

I cant upgrade vue2 to vue3 yet waiting for time from the client. I just need this to run with node 18.

Comment: This is irrelevant to vue 2/3, it's just a framework that works in a browser, while you have a problem with build tool. Do not remove package-lock without knowing why this is necessary, this will add more problems. You likely need to update vue cli to 5, and probably some other dev dependencies to match it.